# How to check if vector is a single NA value without length warning and without suppression

Tags: r

I have a function with `NA` as a default, but if not `NA` should be a character vector not restricted to size 1. I have a check to validate these, but `is.na` produces the standard warning when the vector is a character vector with `length` greater than 1.

```r
so_function <- function(x = NA) {
  if (!(is.na(x) | is.character(x))) {
    stop("This was just an example for you SO!")
  }
}

so_function(c("A", "B"))
#> Warning in if (!(is.na(x) | is.character(x))) {: the condition has length >
#> 1 and only the first element will be used
```

An option to prevent the warning I came up with was to use `identical`:

```r
so_function <- function(x = NA) {
  if (!(identical(x, NA) | is.character(x))) {
    stop("This was just an example for you SO!")
  }
}
```

My issue here is that this function will generally be taking Excel sheet data loaded into R as inputs, and the `NA` values generated from that are often `NA_character_`, `NA_integer_`, and `NA_real_`, so `identical(x, NA)` is often `FALSE` when I actually need it to be `TRUE`.

For the broader context,  I am experiencing this issue for S3 classes I am creating for a package, and the function below approximates how I am validating multiple attributes for that class, which is when the warnings are appearing. Because of this, I am trying to avoid suppressing warnings as the solution, so would be interested to know what best practice exists to solve this issue.

**Edit**

In order to make use cases clearer, this is validating attributes for a class, where I want to ensure the attribute is either a single `NA` value, or a character vector of any length:

```r
so_function(NA_character_) # should pass
so_function(NA_integer_) # should pass
so_function(c(NA, NA)) # should fail
so_function(c("A", "B")) # should pass
so_function(c(1, 2, 3)) # should fail
```

Comment: does `identical(as.character(x), NA_character_)` do what you want?  Can you provide a series of test cases?

Comment: Issue would be that the attribute might be `NA_integer_`, `NA_real_` or even `NA_logical_` possibly. I guess I could chain the 4 options (thankfully no `NA_complex_` haha!), and could create a helper function to keep it concise, but thought maybe there's something I'm unaware of for this.

Comment: Have added use cases for future reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The length warning comes from the use of `if`, which expects a length 1 vector, and `is.na` which is vectorised.

You could use `any` or `all` around the `is.na` to compress it to a length 1 vector but there may be edge cases where it doesn't work as you expect so I would use shortcircuit evaluation to check it is length 1 on the `is.na` check:

```
so_function <- function(x = NA) {
  if (!((length(x)==1 && is.na(x)) | is.character(x))) {
    stop("This was just an example for you SO!")
  }
}

so_function(NA_character_) # should pass

so_function(NA_integer_) # should pass

so_function(c(NA, NA)) # should fail
Error in so_function(c(NA, NA)) : This was just an example for you SO!

so_function(c("A", "B")) # should pass

so_function(c(1, 2, 3)) # should fail
Error in so_function(c(1, 2, 3)) : This was just an example for you SO!
```

Another option is to use `NULL` as the default value instead.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks James. I didn't use `NULL` as the default value since the function will primarily not be taking direct user input, but applied across the data frame vectors, so would need to check for `NA` as well as `NULL` I guess (and was trying to minimize the amount of checks).

Comment: @caldwellst I've understood the problem better with your new examples and edited it slightly to satisfy them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem arises from `is.na()` - it is a vectorized function which produces a vector as an output. `is.character(x)` on the other hand is not vectorized so it only will output a single value.

You can leverage apply-like functions to overcome this e.g.

```
sapply(c("a", NA, 5), is.character)
```

`if` also functions similarly - you are better off using `ifelse` for by-element comparison.
I don't think I quite grasped what you what do to with you function but it could rewritten like this:

```
so_function_2 <- function(x = NA) {
  condit <- !(is.na(x) | sapply(x, is.character))
  ifelse(condit, "This was just an example for you SO!", "FALSE")
}
```

Comment: Have added use cases so it's clearer what I'm trying to do. Don't want to vectorize because I am looking to valid the entire vector as an attribute.

Comment: Also, `c("a", NA, 5)` is a character vector, `apply` would only work here if I was trying to work across multiple vectors in a `list` or `data.frame`. Your solution of `so_function_2(c("a", NA, 5))` would result in `FALSE FALSE FALSE` and never trigger the condition.