# In if (is.na(x)) { : condition has length and just first element will be used in R

Tags: r, string, list, date, lapply

I am trying to convert strings to date data class for specific columns in an specific df inside a list;
As they come in excel format I am currently using `excel_numeric_to_date` from `janitor` package to convert them;

However when I apply the next code, I am running into lot of warnings and the output returns NA's instead of dates.

```
date_columns <- c("date1", "date2", "date3", "date4")



fun_excel_date <- function(x){
  if(is.na(x)){
    return(NA)
  } else {
    excel_numeric_to_date(as.numeric(
      as.character(x)
    ), date_system = "modern")
  }
}


df_list[["input_1"]][date_columns] <- lapply(
  df_list[["input_1"]][date_columns],
  fun_excel_date
)
```

Console output:

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (is.na(x)) { :
  la condición tiene longitud > 1 y sólo el primer elemento será usado
2: In if (is.na(x)) { :
  la condición tiene longitud > 1 y sólo el primer elemento será usado
3: In if (is.na(x)) { :
  la condición tiene longitud > 1 y sólo el primer elemento será usado
4: In if (is.na(x)) { :
  la condición tiene longitud > 1 y sólo el primer elemento será usado
5: In if (is.na(x)) { :
  la condición tiene longitud > 1 y sólo el primer elemento será usado
6: In if (is.na(x)) { :
  la condición tiene longitud > 1 y sólo el primer elemento será usado
7: In if (is.na(x)) { :
  la condición tiene longitud > 1 y sólo el primer elemento será usado
8: In if (is.na(x)) { :
  la condición tiene longitud > 1 y sólo el primer elemento será usado
```

Is there any other way to apply this function?

Comment: the variable to be passed to the `if` condition  must contain only 1 element. eg. `if(3>2)` and not `if (3>1:2)`. So in your case, `x` is a vector and `is.na(x)` returns a vector, but `if` does not take a vector hence the warning

Comment: Why do you even need this conditional block? `janitor::excel_numeric_to_date()` already handles NA values fine.

`> janitor::excel_numeric_to_date(c(40000, 40001, NA, 40002), date_system = "modern")` returns `[1] "2009-07-06" "2009-07-07" NA           "2009-07-08"`

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem discussed in general [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58856951/how-to-check-if-vector-is-a-single-na-value-without-length-warning-and-without-s). For your specific code, the following should do what you expect:

```
if(length(x) == 1 && is.na(x)){
      return(NA)
} else {
...
```